# How to get a value in map by point?

Tags: java

I have a `point` class:

```
class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x,int y) 
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}
```

And I have a `map` to store the values:

```
Map<Point,Integer> map = new HashMap<Point,Integer>();
map.put(new point(1,1)) = 10;
```

I want to get the values in `map` by a definite point:

```
map.get(new point(1,1));
```

but it returns `null`.
It may because of the difference of their reference.
I want to know how to fix it,instead of using a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Just implement `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` in `Point`, to define what you consider equal points.

Comment: Also, in case a class is used as a key in map, its advisable to keep it immutable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when using structures like Map class you should implement the equals and hashCode method so when the get method of Map get called these methods will call respectively

something like this:

```
class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        Point point = (Point) o;
        return x == point.x && y == point.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```